# My simple jQuery fadeOut is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, fadeout

I am trying to do something with simple jquery but its not working, even I think that I did the code well. Here is mycode, please someone help me!!

```
    <body>
    <div id="content">
    <div id="welco"><img id="wks" src="images/WKS.png" height="200px" /></div>
        <div id="cont">
            <div id="north-region">

            </div>
            <div id="west-region">

            </div>
            <div id="south-region">

            </div>
            <div id="southeast-region">

            </div>
            <div id="east-region">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#wks").fadeOut(1000,"swing");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: looks like you either haven't sourced jquery or you changed the namespace. works here: http://jsfiddle.net/YFr6j/

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: what error are you gettng? check consol.

Comment: this is working just fine for me [http://jsfiddle.net/sHFbJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/sHFbJ/)

Comment: what is not working ? Keep in mind that since you start the fadeout on DOM ready, the fadeout might complete before the image is loaded..

Comment: No error, nothing, the image appears on browser and it doesnt hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a jsfiddle of your example and it works ok.

http://jsfiddle.net/yM3yK/

Im linking you also a html file u are using with corrected code.

http://www.sendspace.com/file/euquxo

I moved the script to the head tag.

```
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function (){
                $("#wks").fadeOut(1000,"swing");
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

P.s.: If this helped, mark it as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Now works perfect :) thank you very much, I am learning the jquery, and it looks like that I forget to put any src code. Thank you again

Comment: You're welcome! Dont forget to mark it as accepted answer for other users seeking the same help!